# Enough, or not enough: that is the question

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

I have an account on StackOverflow Careers with one unlocked feature. It's Get discovered by companies and it requires four conditions, all four of which are completed:

- Fill out your personal statement (200+ characters)
- Add at least one record of work experience or education
- Add at least two technologies you like
- Opt in to get discovered

But the Apply to jobs feature is blocked because I hadn't complete first condition of these three:

- Fill out your personal statement (200+ characters)
- Add at least one record of work experience or education
- Pick a custom profile URL

So how is it possible that the condition has been met and has not been met? Did my avatar caused participation in the Schrödinger's experiment?

At this moment the personal statement contains only 184 characters and I can't remember that it was ever filled previously.

[image: Schrödinger's condition]

Comment: Bug added to the tracker. Should be fixed before the full launch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for the report, Yoh! <3

The CV editor was already undergoing refinements to avoid this kind of inconsistent behavior. We have just shipped those changes and you shouldn't be noticing this behavior now.